# Graylog remove_field(to_string($message.message)) not working

Tags: graylog, graylog3

I do log manangement with Graylog. I want to destroy some fields after parsing the logs. I'm trying to destroy the message field. But I couldn't. I want to delete this area to take up less space.

**Is there a way to do this?**

```
remove_field(to_string($message.message));
```

**or**

```
remove_field("message");
```

**or**

```
set_field("test", $message.message);
remove_field(to_string($message.message));
```

Answer (score 1):

He Birol,

the field `message` is actually a reserved field. So that, `timestamp` and `source` can't be removed.

You can overwrite the content of the field `message` with zero - or a whitespace (or any other text). But removing this will not work.

Jan